# Will apps that use telprompt be rejected

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, telprompt

In order to return to app after call, I use telprompt instead of tel. Codes like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://10086"]];
```

Somebody says that it will be rejected by apple because telpromt is not the public URL Scheme. But I didn't find a certain answer - Yes or No. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [handleopenurl.com](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/phone) an index for iOS URL schemes.

I do not know telprompt. Why not just use tel://10086?

Comment: Because tel://10086 will come to home view after call, but telprompt://10086 will return the app after call.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: You may got a better answer by asking that in the Apple developer forum. But it would be nice to post it here too, if you got an answer.

Comment: I know this is old but I did find a couple people claiming their apps were approved using telprompt: 
"I've submited my app that uses telpromt with shared application without the uiwebkit and has been successfully approved by apple.
answered January 19, 2013

Pablo Alejandro Junge"

Comment: Also, telprompt:/ shows the number and asks for confirmation before starting the call. Definetely better than placing the call directly.

Comment: I submitted an app using telprompt in 2011 and can confirm that the app was accepted.

Comment: Xcode 14 iOS 16. These two links are the same: Show call confirmation > Open Phone app and call the phone number > go back to app when hang up phone.

Answer (score 14):

`telprompt://` and `tel://` are both valid custom URL scheme of iOS, for now.

Since Apple does not have documentation on `telprompt`, its functionality  may be removed without notice (low chance though).

*Note: Their behavior is different. The former one is better, as it won't dial the number directly and won't stay at Phone app after call.*

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that with iOS 8.0 the `tel://` URL scheme will also return to the app after the call. The only difference now is that with `telprompt://` the app will prompt before starting the call.

Answer (score 0):

This will not get your application rejected as I already uploaded an application with this and it is on the App Store now.